# Loop semantics(literal)

Tags: semantics

If you don't care what your variables are called LOOK AWAY!!

Anyway, lets say I have a loop

```
for (int i = start; i < whatisthis; i++) {
    //something
}
```

I'm not sure what to call "whatisthis", usually I can call it the length or the size of the relevant collection but its not always strictly true, if start != 0 then it cannot be the length. Its not the length of the stretch either since its in fact start + length of the stretch. Can't call it the end since its end+1 so what do you call it?

Serious problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whatisthis` has no name. The whole condition `i < whatisthis` is a *termination condition*, and `whatisthis` is merely part of that condition.

If you're looking for advice about what to name the variable, `limit` works pretty well if it's not a length or a size. You could also prefix it with `max_` or `min_`. For example, `max_row` or `min_timeout`.